# Nested IF statement formula field for custom labels

Tags: formula

Current formula is running an error.

```
IF(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Contracts",
    $Label.Opp1_Record_Type
),
IF( 
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Customer",
    $Label.Opp2_Record_Type
),
IF( 
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Requirements", 
    $Label.Opp3_Record_Type
),
IF( 
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Solutions",
    $Label.Opp4_Record_Type
),
IF( 
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Standard",
    $Label.Opp5_Record_Type
)
```

Comment: Remember people, when you need help with an error, it _really helps if you include the error message_. It's a simple enough issue in this case, but don't make it harder than it needs to be to answer your question. Details, details, details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry about that. All I am getting is a syntax error - I am trying to use this formula field to tie the custom labels to specific records type from Leads Record types to the Opportunity Record types upon conversion as the business use case (I found an example online) The example online was: IF(RecordType.DeveloperName=”Lead1″, $Label.Opp1_Record_Type, $Label.Opp2_Record_Type), but I have r record types I am trying to reference/connect

Comment: You are missing some closing parentheses, see [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/troubleshooting_formulas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF` statements are in the form `IF(condition, trueValue, falseValue)`, If you nest them, it ends up adding parentheses at the end: `IF(condition, trueValue, IF(condition, trueValue, IF(condition, trueValue, falseValue)))`.

Your formula should therefore read like:

```
IF(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Contracts",
    $Label.Opp1_Record_Type,
    IF( 
        RecordType.DeveloperName = "Customer",
        $Label.Opp2_Record_Type,
        IF( 
            RecordType.DeveloperName = "Requirements", 
            $Label.Opp3_Record_Type,
            IF( 
                RecordType.DeveloperName = "Solutions",
                $Label.Opp4_Record_Type,
                IF(
                    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Standard",
                    $Label.Opp5_Record_Type,
                    ""
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, in this situation, where you're comparing one field to multiple values, it's better to use `CASE`:

```
CASE(
    RecordType.DeveloperName,
    "Contracts", $Label.Opp1_Record_Type,
    "Customer", $Label.Opp2_Record_Type,
    "Requirements", $Label.Opp3_Record_Type,
    "Solutions", $Label.Opp4_Record_Type,
    "Standard", $Label.Opp5_Record_Type,
    ""
)
```

Which is in the form `CASE(FIELD, value1, result1, value2, result2, ..., defaultValue)`.